# Where can I find Monero public RPC nodes I can connect to?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, remote-node, public-node

Is there a public list of public monero RPC nodes I can use for testing purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Monero 0.15.0.0, you can use the `public_nodes` command in monero-wallet-cli. It will query your daemon, as the list is now shared over the P2P network. This can be used in tandem with the bootstrap daemon mode, so you can use RPC services before your node has finished syncing.

Similarly, the `print_pl` daemon command now accepts a `publicrpc` parameter to filter nodes by whether they offer publicly accessible RPC.

Yes, you do need a daemon in order to use those, and this is intended. If you really cannot spare the space for a blockchain (currently around 25 GB if pruned), then you can use the daemon on no-sync bootstrap mode, with the `--no-sync` daemon parameter. This will avoid syncing the blockchain while still allowing you access to the P2P public RPC nodes list without having to go through a central repository.